# Parallel Dynamic Programming Travel Salesman

Tags: parallel-processing, dynamic-programming, traveling-salesman

Are there any papers discussing how to solve the travel salesman problem with parallel dynamic programming?

Answer (score 1):

Entering `parallel dynamic programming traveling salesman` as a search in Google Scholar gave [some promising results](http://scholar.google.nl/scholar?hl=nl&q=parallel%20dynamic%20programming%20traveling%20salesman&btnG=Zoeken&lr=&as_ylo=&as_vis=0). Inspect those hits and see if you find anything that suits you.